# Is function object created by `new` constructor treated as mutable object in javascript?

Tags: javascript, calling-convention, function-object

From study, I understood that in javascript, **mutable objects**() are treated by **call-by-reference**, and **immutable objects** are treated by **call-by-value** calling convention.

Let's say I use this kind of data,

```
var Node = function(data) {
  this.data = data;
  this.next = null;
};

var v = new Node(0);
```

is `v` a mutable object or an immutable object??

Comment: What is immutable object? Do you mean primitive types?

Comment: Every parameter in JavaScript is passed by value. Your variable is an object.

Comment: It is mutable as you can change/add/remove properties from the object

Comment: @Pointy Can you explain more _"Every parameter in JavaScript is passed by value"_. Consider a function `const f = (x) => x` And if we pass a object `{a:1}` to it. It will be passed by reference.

Comment: @MaheerAli Every object is a reference value, but still every argument is passed by value. If you call `f(y)`, then reassigning to `x` cannot change what `y` holds.

Comment: @MaheerAli the terminology is confusing and unfortunate, and dates from before "objects" were things people talked about in programming. Almost all modern programming languages are pass-by-value because it's generally easier to implement and much less weird.

Comment: @Bergi I think `call by sharing` is the right terminology for arguments?

Comment: @Sagivb.g Yes, if we pass mutable things such as objects by value (without copying their contents), then we can also name that "call by sharing".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all lets understand what is the [`new` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new) doing inside the created execution context behind the scenes:

It will:

1. Create a new Object (and attach it to the `this` label)
2. That new object's `__proto__` property will reference the function's `prototype` property
3. It will return the newly created object (if you are not explicitly returning an object)

So in your case:

```
var v = new Node(0);
```

`v` is actually an `Object` (the one that created and returned via `new`) and objects in JavaScript are mutable.

[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures#Primitive_values) are the primitives (immutable) types:
Boolean
Null
Undefined
Number
String
Symbol (new in ECMAScript 6)

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript don't have "immutable objects" there 2 types:

1) primitives - immutable

2) Object - mutable

update: [object freeze](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze) can give some "immutable"

Answer (score 1):

It is mutable, as you can see from this working example.

```js
var Node = function(data) {
  this.data = data;
  this.next = null;
};

var v = new Node(0);

v.myNewAttribute = 'foobar';

var elemDiv = document.createElement('div');
elemDiv.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(v);
document.body.appendChild(elemDiv);
```

Answer (score 1):

`v` is a **mutable** object. To change this object to an **immutable** object use the `Object.freeze()` method.

**Example:**

```js
var Node = function(data) {
  this.data = data;
  this.next = null;
};

var v = new Node(0); // "v" object is mutable  
v.data = 1;          // The "data" property value will change
console.log(v);

Object.freeze(v); // "v" object is immutable  

v.data = 2;       // The "data" property value will NOT change

console.log(v);
```

> The **Object.freeze()** method freezes an object. A frozen object can no longer be changed; freezing an object prevents new properties from being added to it, existing properties from being removed, prevents changing the enumerability, configurability, or writability of existing properties, and prevents the values of existing properties from being changed. In addition, freezing an object also prevents its prototype from being changed. freeze() returns the same object that was passed in. [more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze)